# SQL View Select only last of self referencing chain

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that stores a string specifying user's permissions. I have a column `previous` that has a FK to `id` in the same table, and this way linking to the previous version of the permissions. What I want to do is create a view that will only show the last of this chain (the most up-to-date one). The original one does not have any previous value set. The table than looks like this:

```
+-------+-------+------+----------+---------+
| ID    | PERMS | USER | PREVIOUS | VERSION |
+-------+-------+------+----------+---------+
| GUID1 | set1  | John |          | 1       |
| GUID2 | set2  | Dave |          | 1       |
| GUID3 | set3  | John | GUID1    | 2       |
| GUID4 | set4  | Phil |          | 1       |
| GUID5 | set5  | John | GUID3    | 3       |
| GUID6 | set6  | Dave | GUID2    | 2       |
```

and so on...

What I want to get from the view is just John's set5, Dave's set6 and Phil's set4. Google search didn't bring anything useful, surprisingly...

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT ID,PERMS,USERS,PREVIOUS,VERSION
          FROM 
          (select ID,PERMS,USERS,PREVIOUS,VERSION,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  USERS ORDER BY VERSION DESC) rn
          from Tab) A where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by version field

```
select * 
  from table as T
 where version = 
       ( select max(version)
           from table 
          where User = T.User )
```

Comment: as @vianov mentioned CTE is not needed because in table is latest version number of permission

Answer (score 0):

This worked. It basically groups the permissions by the user to whom it belongs, numbers each row and then selects only those with rk=1.

```
WITH summary AS (
    SELECT p.id, 
        p.perms,
        p.user,
        p.previous,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.user 
            ORDER BY p.version DESC) AS rk
FROM dbo.permissions p)
SELECT s.id, 
    s.user,
    s.perms,
    s.previous
    FROM summary s
    WHERE s.rk = 1
```

Code taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3800572/6241823